# Eclipse IDE, viewing variables in the terminal when developing Android Applications

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am developing my android applications with the Eclipse IDE. It occoured to me on occasions I would like to check the state of a variable. For instance when I recieve some data over a socket connection and store it in a String variable I would like to be able to check that what is being sent is correct.

I have read that the `System.out.println(myvariable);`and `log.d(myvairable)` should write the request to the android log which can be accessed via Window - Show View - Logcat. However this does not appear to be the case for me. (I can view the log, however nothing is appearing)

So my question is, what is the appropriate way to display a variable in the terminal (equivalent) when developing android applications in the Eclipse IDE.

Thankyou in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The appropriate way is `Log.d("YourApplicationName", "YourMessage")`.
This will write a debug message to the console. You can also write an error message with `Log.e`, a warning message with `Log.w`, an info message with `Log.i` and a verbose message with `Log.v`.

If you do not see it in Eclipse, this is perhaps because the default verbosity do not display debug messages. Look if there is an option to change this or use `adb logcat` in a terminal.